# Third Party Visual Studio Stylesheet / CSS Editor

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010, stylesheet

Any good (free) style sheet editors that I can use with visual studio?  I recently found a resource editor that I found was better than the default version that opens .resx files.  I'm thinking there may be some improved stylesheet editors available.

Comment: Good question! I'd also like to know if there's something better than the default VS2010 editor.

Comment: What resource editor have you found?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about replacements for the stylesheet editor, but there are 2 new alternatives to coding CSS by hand:

[LESS](http://lesscss.org/) introduces variables and inheritance within your CSS at the expense of client-side (or server-side) processing. Can also be run as at build-time.

[SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) lets you wrap your CSS rules hierarchically to make them MUCH more organized and readable.

Support for both are included in Visual Studio extension called [Mindscape Web Workbench](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench). ([VS Extension Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2b96d16a-c986-4501-8f97-8008f9db141a))